# How to set php number_format to display decimal to 40 places

Tags: php

Simplified example.

When I run a large decimal number through through number_format (to change decimal / comma types) I get hit with floating point inaccuracies.

```
<?php
$number = " 0.83333333333333333333333333333333333333";    
echo number_format($number,40,'!','y'); // result: 0!83333333333333337034076748750521801412
?>
```

Is there a simple way to set it so php is accurate to a higher decimal point?

Comment: What do you need that kind of precison for?

Comment: In this specific example it's actually for repeating decimal display, which is the only reason I noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of approximately 1.8e308 with a precision of roughly **14 decimal digits** is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

See more about [floating points number](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

An example about floating point numbers you can read here [https://floating-point-gui.de](https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)